# Отображение выпадающего списка внутри блока

Tags: html, css, html5

У меня есть блок для которого заданы размеры (width=50px; height=50px)
Внутри него есть кнопка по клике на которую выпадает список. Но этот список прячется внутрь родителя. Фото прикрепляю. 
Как можно сделать так, чтобы этот список выходил за границы родителя. То есть не был привязан к нему, а отображался нормально?

[image: l]

Comment: лучше одна строчка кода, чем миллион слов (с)

Comment: @Sevastopol' мне нужно, чтобы была возможность прокрутить родителя если элементы не помещаются.